# Chart.js different color for negative/positive chart bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartjs

[Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js): Tentando colocar uma cor para valores positivos e outra cor para valores negativos no gráfico.

Funciona bem se houver pelo menos um valor negativo:

Veja https://jsfiddle.net/c1w5Laee/78/

Mas tem algo errado se todos os valores forem positivos (sem nenhum valor negativo):

Veja https://jsfiddle.net/c1w5Laee/80/

O que está errado neste código?

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade está tudo certo, só que o gráfico está começando a partir do valor mais baixo, tem uma opção para setar como `0` o valor minimo do eixo Y:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    //Escalas
    scales: {
          yAxes: [{ //Eixo Y
              display: true,
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true   //Começa no zero
              }
          }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente não estava errado... mas olhei tudo várias vezes e não tinha visto os valores do eixo Y (risos!). Muito obrigado! +1

Comment: Sem problemas ! ^^, é normal essas coisas passarem despercebidas mesmo.